# How can I make python request module asyncio and aiohttp

Tags: python

```py
def get_ship_position(ship_id):
    import requests

    url ="https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:{}".format(ship_id)
    

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()


def main():
    from time import perf_counter
    start = perf_counter()
    i = 7550
    while (i <= 9999 ):
        i+=1
        try:

            data = get_ship_position(i)
            with open("marinetraffic.txt","a",encoding="utf-8") as bos:  
                print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}x{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(data["mmsi"], data["imo"],data["name"],data["nameAis"],data["type"],data["typeSpecific"],data["yearBuilt"],data["length"],data["breadth"],data["callsign"],data["country"],data["deadweight"],data["grossTonnage"],data["homePort"],data["status"]),file=bos) 
                print(i,"Yazdı")

        except Exception:
            print(i,"Hata")
            with open("marinetraffichata.txt","a",encoding="utf-8") as hata:
                print("Hata",i,file=hata)
            pass
    stop = perf_counter()        
    print("çalışılan süre:", stop - start,"saniye")

           # return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

I am progressing very slowly with the request module, how can I make the code run fast? I've seen the aiohttp and async modules and they are really fast. How can I adapt my own code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `asyncio` and `aiohttp` is certainly one way of being able to do concurrent URL retrievals. But I am wondering if it is the best way given (1) you are already using `requests` and (2) you want to retrieve 2450 URLs, but not necessarily all at the same time.

By using a multithreading pool of size N, you would have N threads concurrently retrieving up to N URLs. By setting an "appropriate" value for N you can control the degree of concurrency. Performance could improve by increasing N but at some point as N got larger, performance could start to decrease. There is also the possibility that the website might think you are performing a Denial of Service attack by making so many concurrent requests.

In the code below I am using a value of 64 for N and creating a `Session` instance for doing the retrievals, which should also improve performance. I am using method `multiprocessing.pool.Threadpool.imap` to process the returned `data` elements as they become available. This method returns an iterator that when iterated will return the next return value from your worker function, `get_ship_position`. However, I am explicitly using method `next` to iterate so that I can individually handle exceptions that are raised by `get_ship_posiion`. If I were to use instead `for data in pool.imap(worker, range(7551, 10_001))` to iterate then once an exception is raised by an invocation of `get_ship_position`, I would not be able to continue iterating subsequent results.

```py
def get_ship_position(session, ship_id):

    url ="https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:{}".format(ship_id)



    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    return response.json()


def main():
    from time import perf_counter
    import requests
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    from functools import partial

    start = perf_counter()

    with requests.Session() as session:
        headers = {
            "accept": "application/json",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
            "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
        }
        session.headers = headers

        with ThreadPool(64) as pool:
            worker = partial(get_ship_position, session)
            it = pool.imap(worker, range(7551, 10_001))
            i = 7550
            with open("marinetraffic.txt","a",encoding="utf-8") as f:
                while True:
                    i += 1
                    try:
                        data = next(it)
                        print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}x{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(data["mmsi"], data["imo"],data["name"],data["nameAis"],data["type"],data["typeSpecific"],data["yearBuilt"],data["length"],data["breadth"],data["callsign"],data["country"],data["deadweight"],data["grossTonnage"],data["homePort"],data["status"]),file=f)
                        print(i,"Yazdı")
                    except StopIteration:
                        break
                    except Exception:
                        print(i,"Hata")
                        print("Hata",i,file=f)

    stop = perf_counter()
    print("çalışılan süre:", stop - start,"saniye")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

**Using `asyncio` and `aiohttp`**

The following code uses `asyncio` and `aiohttp`. A semaphore set to 64 controls the number of coroutines that can be running concurrently so that you can control the number of concurrent get requests are made. Again, this number, set to 64, can be adjusted to see how performance varies.

```py
import asyncio

async def get_ship_position(session, ship_id):

    url ="https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/vesselDetails/vesselInfo/shipid:{}".format(ship_id)
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        status = response.status
        if status != 200:
            raise Exception(f'Bad status: {status}')
        return await response.json()

async def bounded_fetch(sem, session, ship_id):
    async with sem:
        result = await get_ship_position(session, ship_id)
        return result

async def main():
    from time import perf_counter
    import aiohttp

    start = perf_counter()

    headers = {
        "accept": "application/json",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(64)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*(bounded_fetch(sem, session, i) for i in range(7551, 10_001)), return_exceptions=True)
        with open("marinetraffic.txt","a",encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for i, data in enumerate(responses, start=7551):
                if isinstance(data, Exception):
                    print(i,"Hata")
                    print("Hata",i,file=f)
                else:
                    print("{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}x{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(data["mmsi"], data["imo"],data["name"],data["nameAis"],data["type"],data["typeSpecific"],data["yearBuilt"],data["length"],data["breadth"],data["callsign"],data["country"],data["deadweight"],data["grossTonnage"],data["homePort"],data["status"]),file=f)
                    print(i,"Yazdı")

    stop = perf_counter()
    print("çalışılan süre:", stop - start,"saniye")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    rc = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Note**

With either version successive runs can produce widely different run times.

**Update**

If you want to write results to the output file as results are returned instead of after all coroutines have completed then try:

```py
   ... # code omitted
    import aiofiles

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        sem = asyncio.Semaphore(64)
        tasks = [asyncio.create_task(bounded_fetch(sem, session, i)) for i in range(7551, 10_001)]
        async with aiofiles.open("marinetraffic.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for i, task in enumerate(tasks, start=7551):
                try:
                    await task
                    data = task.result()
                    record = "{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}x{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\n".format(data["mmsi"], data["imo"],data["name"],data["nameAis"],data["type"],data["typeSpecific"],data["yearBuilt"],data["length"],data["breadth"],data["callsign"],data["country"],data["deadweight"],data["grossTonnage"],data["homePort"],data["status"])
                    await f.write(record)
                    print(i,"Yazdı")
                except:
                    print(i,"Hata")
                    print("Hata",i,file=f)

                    print(i,"Yazdı")
                except:
                    print(i,"Hata")
                    print("Hata",i,file=f)
    ... # code omitted
```

Comment: thank you very much. I didn't expect it to be as fast as the block of code you wrote. With ThreadPool, I actually got 5 hours of data in 5 minutes. If I ask one more question, will accepted cookies reduce pc performance or are they stored in temporary memory and deleted?

asyncio was a bit slower but according to my code block the room was very good.                I also got this warning
DeprecationWarning: There is no current event loop
   rc = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
I guess it's a normal warning.

Comment: Any cookies returned are stored in session objects in memory and will disappear. Try `rc = asyncio.run(main())`. This should get rid of the warning.

Comment: I should add that depending on your environment doing `asyncio.run(main())` with `aiohttp` can sometimes result in a **RuntimeError: Event loop is closed** exception.

Comment: I used it without any problems, the code block works fine. I've been trying to adapt it for almost a week. Thanks for your effort